# References or guidelines for PCB connectors

Tags: connector

Are there references or guidelines to establishing which pins is recommended to use for the power, which for the ground, which for the analog signals, etc. on the various poles of the PCB connectors?

For example, in a board to board connector where is recommended to place the gnd? on one ends near the pins of Vcc or is better to separate vcc and gnd by placing it each other at the two ends. Or again, where is it better to place a pin for analog signals? Maybe between two pins of gnd?

Comment: It totally depends on the application and some applications all pins can be "don't care" whilst other applications requires signals to be set on pins surrounded by 0 volts. Others require than signal pins are routed together (close). This question exposes many variations and because of this I'm voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: @Andyaka giving an answer on what determines which policy to apply or where to find it would be a good answer. To me looks quite possible to answer this question, it's not too broad...

Comment: Where to find the information is not a good answer as I understand stack exchange’s guidelines. As to policy, there are no firm or fixed in stone rules that make it easy to answer. The question is too broad and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no general guidelines that cover all the 1000s of kinds of PCB connectors.

For specific types of connectors, there may be very strict requirements. For example, if you have a USB connector, it's very definitely required to connect the pins according to the USB standard:

[image]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USB.svg))

Answer (score 0):

Besides from standards' required specifics, on some connectors you might have some function specific pins, such as bigger pins dedicated to power, like this connector from samtec:

[image: Samtec PowerStrip with EXTreme Ten60Power]
([image source](https://blog.samtec.com/post/60a-power-socket-now-available-with-press-fit-termination/))
But we are stating the obvious here.

You may also have longer or shorter pins for hot-plug connectors, where you want to be sure to connect something before or after something else is connected. Such as the one that worried this SE user: https://superuser.com/questions/1030382/broken-connectors-pins-on-graphics-card. This can also be seen in board to board connectors. See also this example from a maxim appnote: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4705.

Generally, you wouldn't want to mix and put close together analog signals and high speed digital signals, because the noise produced by the digital signals can be coupled to the analog pins and generate noise in the analog part of your board.

Answer (score 0):

In general, connector layout follows the same principles as PCB track layout.
You want to...
1) Minimize current loop area by examining where current flows forth and back and route those conductor pairs as close as possible to each other. 
2) Maximize separation for different current loops. It‘s not only galvanic isolation (common signal path), but also capacitive and inductive coupling that is reduced by maximum separation.

To sum it up: Identify all current loops, then minimize and separate them.